# How to change the type of a column from varchar(30) to varcahar(100)?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a table that describes like this:

```
mysql> describe easy_table;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version             | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| city                | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
...
| name                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name_two            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I'm trying to make the city varchar bigger to varchar(100) and this line doesn't work

```
alter table easy_table alter column city varchar(100);
```

this also doesn't work

```
alter table easy_table alter column city varchar(100) not null;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'varchar(100)' at line 1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
alter table easy_table modify column city varchar(100) not null;
```

Comment: `MODIFY` will remove any other meta-data on that column not specified in the statement, so any `DEFAULT` values, `NOT NULL`, etc.. To preserve other meta-data see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914453/change-column-data-type-in-mysql-without-losing-other-metadata-default-notnull).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Modify keyword, not Alter

Answer (score 0):

try

```
alter table easy_table change city city varchar(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table easy_table modify city VARCHAR(100) ;
```

must be you command to change the size of the column.

Please refer to this page.. This is useful link..

http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/p/alter_table.htm